# How to use WCAG requirements for logo text contrast in interface?

Tags: website-design, logo, guides, contrast, accessibility

Please, help!! I've read rules from WCAG (Accessibility Guidelines) for using logo text contrast in the interface. The rule 1.4.3 https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html It is said that "Text that is part of a logo or brand name has no minimum contrast requirement". BUT In the rule 1.4.5 https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-text-presentation.html It is said that "Logotypes (text that is part of a logo or brand name) are considered essential". And we need to follow AA Level of Conformance according to this rule. AND In the rule 1.4.9 https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-text-images.html It is said that "Logotypes (text that is part of a logo or brand name) are considered essential". And we need to follow AAA Level of Conformance.

I wonder where is the key? I have text logo made for website. What rules should I follow in Accessibility Guidelines to make good contrast for logo?

Thanks a million!

Comment: These are *guidelines*. What does your logo look like? Does it have good contrast? If so, don't worry about it. If not, make it contrast better.

Comment: Wait... who reads that stuff anyway ?! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADA compliance for logos can be interpreted to mean that logo text which clearly identifies company or brand needs to have sufficient contrast and readability.  Text that serves  purely decorative purpose does not need to meet the same requirements.  If possible, always err on the side of caution and go with a higher contrast, to avoid spending far greater time arguing with client and ADA auditors.

You can run your logo through Color Check for ADA https://www.oss-usa.com/color-check-ada-image-compliance to see how it fares.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I've been looking for!